# prevent php classes from being extends

Tags: php

some time i trying to decode my own general file
that contain the all important functions in a class
but i think
when i have class like

```
class A {
  public function test($value){
```

and the file encoded

may be some one do that

```
class B extends A {
  public function test($value){
```

and change the whole function that contain my code that i can expose my control

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`final`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) keyword.

Answer (score 3):

```
final class A {
  public function test($value){
```

or

```
class A {
  final public function test($value){
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [final](http://phpbuilder.com/manual/language.oop5.final.php) keyword